# bonding NICs w/o switch

Tags: linux, nic, bonding, bsd

(This may not be possible, but I thought I'd ask just in case it is, as it will save a considerable amount of cash.)

I'm building cluster of sorts that has one **shared** storage unit and two computing units.

I'd wondering if it is possible to bond two 1GBASE-T NICs per computing unit and connect them directly to an identical set of NICs on the storage server without a switch in between and alternate which NIC the packets are being transmitted on and have them reassembled on the other end (mode 0 - round robin?).

This would theoretically increase throughput and of course CPU usage.

We are talking Linux or BSD here. Please do not mention Windows.

There may not be a standard for this, but perhaps there is a piece of software or kernel hack that does this.

Comment: Will work without any problems. Check this topic for sure:

http://serverfault.com/a/172839/117969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linux bonding driver (not sure but expect there is a BSD equivalent) creates software bonds of NICs independent of any particular switch technology. I haven't tried it without a switch but as it's all done client side I suspect it should work exactly the same with a crossover configuration:

http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt

Answer (score 1):

on FreeBSd you have *lagg*. I am using it in the failover mode, but `man lagg` also mentions a loadbalance, roundrobin and lacp as options.